# Error when trying to brew update

Tags: macos, homebrew

> **error:** The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root
> cause and remove .git/gc.log. Automatic cleanup will not be performed
> until the file is removed.
>
> **warning:** There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune'
> to remove them.

brew works fine, he only show this error when i update him

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can fix this issue by running two commands:

```
cd "$(brew --repo)" # Navigate to Homebrew's git repository
git prune && git gc # Remove loose objects
```

To check :

```
cd - # Go back to the original location
brew update
```

Output:

`Already up-to-date.`

Error should be fixed and gone! :)

Comment: `... git prune && git gc`, without dot at the end

Comment: I think there may be another location for the gc.log. To me when I use "find . -name gc.log", I find the file locate here: "./Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/.git/gc.log". Then the first command should be "cd ./Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/" instead of the Brew direction.

Answer (score 5):

If you run `%> locate gc.log` you will likely see something along the lines of this in the output:

```
/usr/local/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-versions/.git/gc.log
```

In this case, to fix the problem, I went to `/usr/local/Library/Taps/caskroom` and ran

`%> git prune`

`%> rm /usr/local/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-versions/.git/gc.log`

and the problem went away.

Answer (score -3):

Also you can reinstall brew

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"

$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```